# angular service передать "окружение штмл"

Tags: angularjs

Задача стоит в следующем:
1.нужно создать форму
2.прилепить нужные данные через инпут
3.установить параметры формы (медот) и файл обработчик и target:_blank
4.засабмитить форму
5.удалить форму.

нужно сделать данный функционал черзе сервис

определение сервиса

```
 (function(){
        "use strict";

        angular.module("app.services").factory('PdfService', function(){
            return {
                print: function(){
                    console.log('printnig');
                }
            };
        });
    })();

определение в 

(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module('app.controllers').controller('ConclusionsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Restangular, $state, $rootScope, $translate, PdfService){


        $scope.print = function() {

            console.log('begin');
            PdfService.print();

        };

    });

})();
```

(лишние методы я повыкидал)

по клику на кнопку отработает метод $scope.print и так далее...

Нашел примеры как реализовать такое через Директивы, но сказали что нужно реализовать через сервис.
Спасибо.

Comment: с чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: я второй день работаю на angular, может не допираю просто, но как могу из сервиса создать форму в вьюхе отправить ее и удалить ее? Проблему вижу в том что не могу получить доступ к html и $scope из сервиса

Comment: _как могу из сервиса создать форму в вьюхе_ - никак - сервис это сервис - он не имеет отношения к разметке. Просто бинди нужные функции обработчики к форме в разметке и все

Comment: из сервиса можно "достучаться" к html черзе глобальгное окно $window и скажем на body поцепить нужную форму и так далее....

Comment: Ага, а можно еще и с помощью jQuery все делать, и даже в сервис/контроллер это все впихнуть, непонятно только зачем тогда ангуляр использовать :)

Comment: Если в ангуляре вы работаете с разметкой где-то кроме директивы (link,compile функции) - значит вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: jQuery )))  спасибо за критику)) буду знать как нужно поступать в таких случаях когда нада работать из DOM

Answer (score 2):

Возможно не совсем понял, но как вариант:

```
    <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" action="server_file.php" method="post" target="_blank" ng-hide="form.hide" ng-submit="form.submit()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.formFctr.data.par1"/>
        <input type="number" ng-model="form.formFctr.data.par2"/>
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Контроллер с фабрикой:

```
    angular.module('form', [])
.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', 'formFctr', function($scope, formFctr){

    $scope.form = {formFctr:formFctr};

    $scope.form.submit = function(){
        var data = $scope.form.formFctr.data;
        $scope.form.hide = true;
    };

}])

.factory('formFctr', function(){
    return{
        data:{
            par1:''
            ,par2:''
//            ,par3:''
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: чуть не то, в html разметке изначально нет формы, ее как раз то нужно создать, "настроить" и отправить, после удалить.

Comment: @IgorKalamurda элементы формы можно реализовать директивой, данные получить через фабрику и отправить с помощью контроллера.